# Trying to render a field when if:false is valid, not working how I expect

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, html

I am trying to render not here when `activity.name` is not present. This would happen if a student doesn't have `extraActivites` in their `JSON payload`. In the picture below and in my provided code you can see I have a `true` and `false` to show that even with it being false it will not be shown on the screen.

All I am trying to solve is getting a false statement to show with text for the student with no activities. Any suggestion on solving this issue?

[image: Image of rendering code]

**HTML:**

```
<template>
    <template for:each={outputResult.classes} for:item="classRecord">
        <div key={classRecord.classNumber}>
            <lightning-accordion>
                <lightning-accordion-section label={classRecord.classNumber}>
                    <template for:each={classRecord.classList} for:item="student">
                        <div key={student.id}>
                            <lightning-button variant="base" label={student.name.first}>
                            </lightning-button>
                            <div>{student.phone.number}|{student.email}</div>
                            <lightning-accordion>
                                <lightning-accordion-section label="Involved Activities">
                                    <template for:each={student.extraActivites} for:item="activity">
                                        <div key={activity.id}>
                                            <div>{activity.name.activityName}</div>
                                            <div if:false={activity.name}>not here</div>
                                            <div if:true={activity.name}>not here</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </template>
                                </lightning-accordion-section>
                            </lightning-accordion>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </lightning-accordion-section>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

**JSON:**

```
"classes": [
    {
      "classNumber": 1,
      "classList": [
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "tristan",
            "last": "berger"
          },
          "id": 1,
          "email": "email@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223456"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 1,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "baking"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "eric",
            "last": "cartman"
          },
          "id": 2,
          "email": "email2@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223457"
          },
          "extraActivites": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "classNumber": 2,
      "classList": [
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "john",
            "last": "doe"
          },
          "id": 3,
          "email": "email3@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223477"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 2,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "baking"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from your previous example, we have to restructure the activities section a little bit. Here's the [updated code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/e1TkCwkFDMgYGxGj3yTC/src/app.html?p=stories).

```
<div>{student.phone.number}|{student.email}</div>
<lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open>
    <lightning-accordion-section label="Involved Activities">
        <div for:each={student.extraActivites} for:item="activity" key={activity.id}>
            {activity.name.activityName}</div>
        <div if:false={student.extraActivites.length}>
            None
        </div>
    </lightning-accordion-section>
</lightning-accordion>
```

From my previous answer, I had been focused on getting the rendering to work at all. This answer focuses on fixing some of the mistakes that were overlooked. To check if there's any activities, we just need to use `if:false={student.extraActivities.length}`; 0 is a [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, which will trigger the optional rendering.

Comment: this was the solution, sorry to have taken to so long. But I was finally able to get back to this.

Comment: @TristanBerger No worries, glad I was able to help out!